# How to find the middle value of an integer without converting it to a string using Python3?

Tags: string, python-3.x, integer, palindrome

While solving the next [smallest palindrome problem](https://github.com/harishvc/challenges/blob/master/string-next-palindrome.py), I had to convert an integer to a string so I can reverse and find the middle value. There has to be a solution - how to find the middle value of an integer without converting it to a string using Python3? Appreciate your assistance. Thanks.

Examples:

1. input=78653, result=6
2. input=7564, result=5

Comment: Could you show us the code that you are currently using to do this, so that we can provide concrete solutions/suggestions?

Comment: @Castaglia I just updated the question with more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a start. 
It needs some tweaking:

```
import math

def mid_digit(n):

    # num of digits
    a = math.trunc(math.log(n,10)+1)    

    # moving half of digits to the right of decimal point
    b = n / 10 ** round(a/2 + 0.5)

    # getting the left most decimal digit
    c = math.trunc(math.modf(b)[0] * 10) 

    return c
```

Comment: for `b` you can use floor division `//` instead `b = n//10**(a//2)` and as result `b` is going to be a int then for `c` you can use modulo 10 to get the last digit `c = b%10` or just return `b%10`. Also if you want to be more general, you need to check for 0 and negatives because `log` is not define in those.